# How do I get Bootstrap Components work with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to get Bootstrap components like Tooltips and Popovers to work with Angular 6, but they dont want to show up.

For Tooltips all what I get is this:
[Tooltip example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NAQ9.png)

Setup:

```
// app.component.html
<div style="text-align:center; padding:100px">
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-placement="top"
    title="Tooltip on top">
    Tooltip on top
</button>
</div>
```

---

```
// styles.css
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

---

```
// angular.json
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

---

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "bootstrap-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

I also wrote a directive in Angular to initialize the tooltip, but the console is giving me an error:

```
// load-tooltip.directive.ts
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var $ :any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLoadTooltip]'
})
export class LoadTooltipDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    $(el.nativeElement).tooltip();
  }
}
```

---

```
// console.log
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at new LoadTooltipDirective (load-tooltip.directive.ts:11)
    at createClass (core.js:9302)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9187)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10407)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10723)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10642)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10435)
    at createRootView (core.js:10321)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11352)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10839)
```

Here is an working example with Angular 5:
[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhzy2y?file=app%2Fapp.component.css)

So why does it not work in Angular 6? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(I dont want to use ng-bootstrap or similiar.)

Comment: You can try to use ngx-bootstrap: [ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip), [ngx-bootstrap/#/popover](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover)

Comment: Can you try reproducing your issue on stackblitz? Your code looks fine

Comment: Use ngbootstrap: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples

Comment: @Yoolan Did you find a solution without using ngx-bootstrap?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the directive selector "appLoadTooltip" to your button tag. That should do it.

```
<button appLoadTooltip
type="button"
class="btn btn-secondary"
data-toggle="tooltip"
data-placement="top"
title="Tooltip on top">
Tooltip on top
```

Answer (score 1):

In your component:

Import AfterViewInit and ElementRef:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Declare jQuery variable:

```
declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
  ...
})
```

Make sure your component class implements AfterViewInit and inject ElementRef in the constructor:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

...}
```

Now you can access the DOM in ngAfterViewInit using nativeElement (in this case it find all elements with attribute **data-toggle=tooltip** and initializes a tooltip):

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please set `title="Tooltip on top"` to `[title]="'Tooltip on top'"`.
or 
use [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap)